# How show hidden <td> in JQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, html-table

How can I show hidden(disabled) TD elements in standard JQ datepicker?

[image]

I have tried this way, but that doesn't work:

```
$('#datepicker').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(date){
        var dates = $('#datepicker').multiDatesPicker('getDates');

        $('.ui-state-disabled').empty();
        $('.ui-state-disabled').append('<a class="ui-state-default" href="#"> </a>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base [jquery ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#other-months) has 2 attributes to show dates in other months (`showOtherMonths`) and allow them to be selected (`selectOtherMonths`). You should be able to do the same in this extension.

```
$('#datepicker').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true
})
```